# How do I get the cash value in zendov's tycoon kit

Tags: lua, roblox

I was making tycoon game In roblox with the help of zendov's tycoon kit and lately i was making gui to reedem codes if u reedem codes you will get some amount of cash to do that i need to  access the leaderstats cash value I tried to access it like this `game.Players.leaderstats.Cash.Value` But it's not working I got this error leaderstats is not a valid member of Players "Players"
[this is the code validator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAdOz.png) as you can see in the image I created leaderstats inside the code and it worked with that. the problem is how do i access the leaderstats cash value from the kit

I tried to see every single code in the kit but it didn't work

Comment: `But it's not working` is still very vague. Errors? Or just no visible result? Did you verify the line is called? Maybe extend the question with relevant code, especially where Cash and leaderstats comes from (No roblox experience, but isn't Players reserved for player only? Why is there a leaderstats)

Answer (score 0):

Zednov's tycoon kit does it differently than just using leaderstats, you need to change it in the ServerStorage.PlayerMoney folder

```
local plr = game.ServerStorage.PlayerMoney:FindFirstChild("yourname")
plr.Value = plr.Value + 100000
```

Change the +100000 to how many cash you want to give.

Answer (score -1):

`leaderstats` is a child of the player, not `game.Players`.

Like luke100000 said `game.Players` is reserved for players.

Try using `game.Players.player.leaderstats.cash.Value` instead of `game.Players.leaderstats.Cash.Value`

Comment: Thank you, but still it's the same I tried to see the errors in the output but there is nothing maybe can you join me in Roblox studio??